# How to change the background color of input text inside a table row when a checkbox is checked

Tags: jquery, html-table, tablerow

I want to change the background color of input text/textarea containing inside a td of a table row, the data is coming from database, each row contains checkbox so when the checkbox is clicked the background color of the input text will change.

```js
$('#myTable .nrml').click(function() {
  var currentRow = $(this).closest("tr");
  var col4 = currentRow.find("td:eq(1)").html();
  alert(col4);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border='1' id="myTable">
  <tr>

    <th>Parameter</th>
    <th>Result</th>
    <th>Normal</th>
    <th>Abornaml Values</th>
    <th>Normal Values</th>
    <th>Critical Values</th>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Glucose</td>
    <td><input class="txtbox" type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="nrml"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="abnrml"></td>
    <td>60-80</td>
    <td>110-120</td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lipid</td>
    <td><input class="txtbox" type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="nrml"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="abnrml"></td>
    <td>55-90</td>
    <td>100-180</td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Keratine</td>
    <td><input class="txtbox" type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="nrml"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="abnrml"></td>
    <td>10-15</td>
    <td>16-20</td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Pressusre</td>
    <td><textarea></textarea></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="nrml"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="abnrml"></td>
    <td>10-15</td>
    <td>16-20</td>

  </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this code it will resolve your issue

`$('#myTable .nrml').click(function() {
     var currentRow=$(this).closest("tr");
     var col4=currentRow.find("td:eq(1) input").addClass("red");
  });`

css :

`.red{ background-color: red  }`

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

using [toggleClass](https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) with the checked boolean

```js
$('#myTable .nrml').click(function() {
  $(this).closest("tr")
   .find("input[type=text], textarea")
   .toggleClass('nrml',this.checked);
});
```

```css
textarea.nrml,input[type=text].nrml { background-color: green }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border='1' id="myTable">
  <tr>

    <th>Parameter</th>
    <th>Result</th>
    <th>Normal</th>
    <th>Abornaml Values</th>
    <th>Normal Values</th>
    <th>Critical Values</th>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Glucose</td>
    <td><input class="txtbox" type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="nrml"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="abnrml"></td>
    <td>60-80</td>
    <td>110-120</td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lipid</td>
    <td><input class="txtbox" type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="nrml"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="abnrml"></td>
    <td>55-90</td>
    <td>100-180</td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Keratine</td>
    <td><input class="txtbox" type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="nrml"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="abnrml"></td>
    <td>10-15</td>
    <td>16-20</td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Pressusre</td>
    <td><textarea></textarea></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="nrml"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="abnrml"></td>
    <td>10-15</td>
    <td>16-20</td>

  </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

use [.toggleClass()](https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)  method to apply class which contains css for input.

```js
$('input.nrml').on('click', function() {
var currentRow=$(this).closest("tr");
 var col4=currentRow.find("td:eq(1)").find('input[type=text], textarea');
 col4.toggleClass('textboxBgColor',this.checked);
});
```

```css
.textboxBgColor {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table border='1' id="myTable">
  <tr>

    <th>Parameter</th>
    <th>Result</th>
    <th>Normal</th>
    <th>Abornaml Values</th>
    <th>Normal Values</th>
    <th>Critical Values</th>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Glucose</td>
    <td><input class="txtbox" type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="nrml"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="abnrml"></td>
    <td>60-80</td>
    <td>110-120</td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lipid</td>
    <td><input class="txtbox" type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="nrml"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="abnrml"></td>
    <td>55-90</td>
    <td>100-180</td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Keratine</td>
    <td><input class="txtbox" type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="nrml"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="abnrml"></td>
    <td>10-15</td>
    <td>16-20</td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Pressusre</td>
    <td><textarea></textarea></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="nrml"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="abnrml"></td>
    <td>10-15</td>
    <td>16-20</td>

  </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Be careful of some answers that will pop up here, they will be fragile (changing your html may break your code).

I'd recommend reading: [Decoupling Your HTML, CSS, and JavaScript](https://philipwalton.com/articles/decoupling-html-css-and-javascript/).

You'll instantly be able to recognize that if someone decides to wrap your textarea, or change your table to `<div>` because they want to use bootstrap, your code no longer works (fragile code).

Instead, introduce some classes that describe what you're trying to do:

```
.input-bg-container

.js-bg-trigger

.input-bg-active

.input-bg-target
```

Update your html:

```
<tr class="input-bg-container">
 <td>Glucose</td>
 <td><input class="txtbox input-bg-target" type="text"></td>
 <td><input type="checkbox" class="nrml js-input-bg"></td>
 <td><input type="checkbox" class="abnrml"></td>
 <td>60-80</td>
 <td>110-120</td>
</tr>
```

update your jQuery:

```
$('.input-bg-container .js-input-bg').on('click', function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  var isChecked = $this.prop('checked');
  var $container = $this.closest('.input-bg-container');
  var $target = $container.find('.input-bg-target');
  var $target.toggleClass('input-bg-active', isChecked);
});
```

Now apply whatever css to the active class you want.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to update your script , Background color of input field will change when you checked corresponding check box , but input field must have value otherwise color will not change

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#myTable .nrml').click(function() {
        var currentRow=$(this).closest("tr");
        var val = currentRow.find("td:eq(1) input").val();
        if (val && this.checked == true) {
            var col4=currentRow.find("td:eq(1) input").css('background-color','green');
        } else {
            var col4=currentRow.find("td:eq(1) input").css('background-color','');
        }
});
</script>
```

Comment: I know i haven't added the check validation but thank you so much

Comment: If it work for you kindly mark as answer , if anything else please let me know